# Problem in updating Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, admob, google-ad-manager, google-mobile-ads

I want to update the Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK pod for removing the instances of UIWebView, but according to the documentation [link](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start), there needs to be a `GADApplicationIdentifier` that has to be added to the Info.plist file in order to initialise the SDK properly. I don't have an admob account, I only use Ad-Manager for showing native ads in the app. Is there any other way to update the SDK without adding the `GADApplicationIdentifier` in Info.plist

Comment: do you have the key that you use for initializing the SDK in the AppDelegate? If you do, just literally move that to the info.plist.

Comment: @Glenn I don't have any key, and it is even not required as per the documentation. I only have two different ad-unit ids that I use for DFP requests

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution for this:
If you don't have an AdMob account and you are showing the ads using AdManager, then you can add the following key `GADIsAdManagerApp` to `YES` in your Info.plist, to initialise the Ads SDK properly with the latest version